# Monitor(DVI-D) but my laptop only has VGA and HDMI port

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, dvi

I am trying to use my new monitor with my laptop(Asus g75v) and my monitor is http://www.asus.com/ca-en/Monitors_Projectors/VG248QE/ the high refresh rate of which only works through the DPI-D port.

So I want to know if I can use a VGA-DVI converter to make that work, and how to get the highest refresh rate(144hz) because I really want to try that for gaming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VGA -> DVI(-D) is hard and expensive, since the analog signals need to be digitized by the 'adapter'.

DVI(-I) -> VGA is easy because the analog lines are included with DVI-I.

HDMI <-> DVI is easy, since HDMI and DVI are electrically compatible for video.

So your best bet is to get an HDMI <-> DVI adapter and use that.

- If you have a DVI cable already [use something like this](http://www.startech.com/Cables/Audio-Video/Video-Adapter/HDMI-to-DVI-D-Video-Cable-Adapter-M-F~HDMIDVIMF):

[image]

- If you have an HDMI cable already [use something like this](http://www.startech.com/Cables/Audio-Video/HDMI/HDMI-Female-to-DVI-Male-Adapter~HDMIDVIFM):

[image]